# Formula for Euler characteristic for quotient space of a CW complex

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

I know that there is [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Inclusion-exclusion_principle) for [Euler characteristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic):

$$\chi(A\cup B)=\chi(A)+\chi(B)-\chi(A\cap B)$$

Is there any formula that links between (for [CW complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CW_complex)) some complex, subcomplex and quotient complex ($\chi(X)$,$\chi(A)$,$\chi(X/A)$)?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: What did you try? Did you work out some examples? Did you try the same method as for the union?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\chi(X)=\chi(A)+\chi(X,A)$, see A. Dold, Lectures on Algebraic Topology, Chapt.V, Prop.5.7.

See also the remark of **studiosus** below.

Comment: You are missing $-1$ in RHS.

Comment: @studiosus: Sorry, I don't understand you.

Comment: Boris: $\chi(X/A)=\chi(X\cup_A CA)= \chi(X) - \chi(A) + \chi(CA)= \chi(X) -\chi(A) +1$. Here $CA$ is the cone over $A$. Thus, $\chi(X)= \chi(X/A)+ \chi(A) -1$.

Comment: @studiosus: Thank you, I corrected the answer.